# What is the best way to remove objects from a List

Tags: java

I have the following logic to remove inactive users in the system, since we cannot remove a row while iterating on the list. Is there a better way to handle this?

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
List<User> removeUsers = new ArrayList<User>();

for (User user : users) {
  if (!user.isActive()) {
      removeUsers.add(user);
  }
}

users.removeAll(removeUsers);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a perfectly fine way to do it IMHO.

Other ways that I might do it, use indexing and remove as you loop through in reverse.

```
for (int i = users.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (!users.get(i).isActive())
    {
        users.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Or create a new list of the items to be kept and replace it with the old list.

```
List<User> newUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
for (User user : users)
{
    if (user.isActive())
    {
        newUsers.add(user);
    }
}
users = newUsers;
```

Can't think of any others at the moment.

Comment: `Iterator.remove()` works well too as [maxkar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767087/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-objects-from-a-list/3767175#3767175) pointed out.

Comment: @abyx: Too much clutter?  Debatable.  Doesn't make it less valid.  Sure I could have added using `Iterator.remove()` to my answer which looks cleaner, I agree.  But I opted to refer to another person's (equally fine) answer instead.

Comment: I'm going to have to up vote this just because abyx down voted it

Comment: +1 "You could iterate backwards and remove as you go through the ArrayList. This has the advantage of subsequent elements not needing to shift and is easier to program than moving forwards." See second answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310532/deleting-objects-from-an-arraylist-in-java

Comment: Oh, and I tend to avoid using foreach loops to remove items from lists as I have seen them throw ConcurrentModificationExceptions even in single threadded apps. I looked this up on the net once and apparently it was due to some bug in Java.

Comment: Edit: ignore my first comment - I misread the other question and cant change it now o_O

Comment: @DrDipshit: That is a very valid point (your second comment).  I too generally stay away from iterators when removing things from the collection I'm iterating.  The behavior of removing things from a collection that is being iterated through can vary between different programming languages and is generally not a good idea to do so.  I guess that explains why I didn't think to remove using the iterator in the first place.  :)

Comment: I find it very very sad that new comers to Java that will search for this simple thing will see as a first answer this awkward solution.

Comment: Note that if the list can be modified by other threads, then using indexing *might* not be a good idea (you can't guarantee that the elements will remain at the same position as when you saw them). The solutions that remove existing elements by reference don't have this problem.

Comment: @JeffM Iterators are fine. The bug I mentioned was specific to using foreach loops IE: your second example.

Answer (score 13):

If you use ArrayList, best way is Jeff M's variant. You may also use your variant, but you should consider to use Set (HashSet or IdentityHashSet) intstead of ArrayList for removeUser. For large amount of data it will have better performance.

But for LinkedList best way will be to use Iterator.remove method:

```
for (Iterator<User> it = users.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
    if (it.next().isActive())
        it.remove();
```

Comment: Oh yeah, Iterator.remove() works for ArrayLists too.  This would be very clean too.

Answer (score 4):

How about using some [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) magic?

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
Iterables.removeIf(users, new Predicate<User>() {

 @Override
 public boolean apply(User user) {
  return !user.isActive();
 }
});
```

If you use the Predicate in several place you could even create a named class fro it and make your code even better:

```
private static final class IsNotActiveUserPredicate implements Predicate<User> {
 @Override
 public boolean apply(User user) {
  return !user.isActive();
 }
}

List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
Iterables.removeIf(users, new IsNotActiveUserPredicate());
```

Answer (score 3):

The way Gosling intended us to do it is using `Iterator.remove`:

```
Iterator<User> it = users.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    if (! it.next().isActive()) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

This might not be the best from a performance perspective if you're using `ArrayList`, but then again, seems like you might want to consider changing to `LinkedList`.

In any way, this is the way to remove elements from a collection while iterating over it.

Comment: iterator is not fail safe.structurally modifying a datastructure is not good.

Comment: @Suresh Another question, what do you mean by "iterator is not fail safe"?

Comment: @Zengr  on iterations u should not remove anyelements , that way the hasNext and next will fail , because u havent notified to the iterator class on datastructure modification(i.e. u have removed an element recently , but u run on an older iterator object.)

Comment: @Suresh - please read the solution, we are calling *Iterator.remove*, that iterator is performing the modification, how will it not be aware of it? The solution works, feel free to check it out.

Comment: @zengr sorry i didnt clearly mention the scenario , this happens if two threads comes to your block of code.

Comment: @zengr please read the follwing post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810560/java-set-iterator-safe-for-removal-of-elements

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
for (int i = users.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (!users.get(i).isActive()) {
    users.remove(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but it came up in a search I was doing, so others might still be getting here. With Java 8, the easiest way is to use the new "removeIf" method on the Collection class like so:

```
users.removeIf(user -> !user.isActive());
```

Easy peasy!
It should be noted that, under the covers, the Java code is using Iterator.remove().

[Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another Guava Version using [Collections2.filter](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter%28java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29):

```
final List<User> activeUsers =
    Lists.newArrayList(Collections2.filter(userList, new Predicate<User>(){

        @Override
        public boolean apply(final User input){
            return input.isActive();
        }
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that is rather efficient with array based lists. This is because it does not need to copy the entire tail with every remove. It uses 2 steps: First all elements that need to be retained are copied to their final position at the beginning of the list and then all remaining elements at the end of the list are removed.

```
public static void removeInactiveUsers( ArrayList<User> users )
{

    int j = 0, len = users.size();
    for( int i = 0; i < len; ++i )
    {
        User user = user.get( i );
        if( user.isActive() )
        { 
            if( i != j )
                users.set( j, user );
            ++j;
        }
    }
    users.removeRange( j, len );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want remove any one object like current object or selected object you can follow as below.

```
    Object currentObject = null;
    for (User user : users)
    {
        if (user.isActive())
        {
            currentObject  = user ;
        }
    }

    if(currentObject != null) {
    users.remove(currentObject);
    }
```