# Remove an object from an ArrayList without (implicitly) looping through it

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I am looping through a list A to find X. Then, if X has been found, it is stored into list B. After this, I want to delete X from list A. As speed is an important issue for my application, I want to delete X from A without looping through A. This should be possible as I already know the location of X in A (I found its position in the first line). How can I do this?

```
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        Object X = methodToGetObjectXFromA();
        B.add(X);
        A.remove(X); // But this part is time consuming, as I unnecessarily loop through A
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to remove objects from a List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767087/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-objects-from-a-list)

Comment: That doesn't seem like a dup. OP isn't just asking how to remove, they're asking how best to remove given that index is already known.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning the object from yhe method, you can return its index and then remove by index:

```
    int idx = methodToGetObjectIndexFromA();
    Object X = A.remove(idx); // But this part is time consuming, as I unnecessarily loop through A
    B.add(X);
```

However, note that the `remove` method may be still slow due to potential move of the array elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an iterator, and if performance is an issue is better you use a LinkedList for the list you want to remove from:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    List<Integer> aList = new LinkedList<>();
    List<Integer> bList = new ArrayList<>();
    aList.add(1);
    aList.add(2);
    aList.add(3);

    int value;
    Iterator<Integer> iter = aList.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        value = iter.next().intValue();
        if (value == 3) {
            bList.add(value);
            iter.remove();
        }
    }

    System.out.println(aList.toString()); //[1, 2]  
    System.out.println(bList.toString()); //[3]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you stored all the objects to remove in a second collection, you may use [`ArrayList#removeAll(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection))

> Removes from this list all of its elements that are contained in the
>   specified collection. 
>   **Parameters**: 
>   c collection containing elements to be removed from this list

In this case, just do

`A.removeAll(B);`

When exiting your loop.

---

### Addition

It calls `ArrayList#batchRemove` which will use a loop to remove the objects but you do not have to do it yourself.