# Removing entries from a list?

Tags: java, list

Take a situation where you have, let's say, an ArrayList that supports a remove function -- it deletes the entry and shifts everything to the right of it left one.

If I want to remove things from the list under a certain condition, I might do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  if (condition) {
    list.remove(i);
    i--;
  }
}
```

but this is ugly and feels hackish. You could do the same with an Iterator, but you shouldn't be altering lists while using iterators.

So what's the non-ugly solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting objects from an ArrayList in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310532/deleting-objects-from-an-arraylist-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Iterators can in fact be used for that purpose, and is what the [Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html) recommends.

This is code provided by the above link under Traversing Collections - Iterators:

```
static void filter(Collection<?> c) {
    for (Iterator<?> it = c.iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
        if (!cond(it.next()))
            it.remove();
}
```

Most importantly, above that example they state:

> Note that `Iterator.remove` is the only safe way to modify a collection
>   during iteration; the behavior is unspecified if the underlying
>   collection is modified in any other way while the iteration is in
>   progress.

Answer (score 1):

I just use a loop, but decrement the counter instead

```
for(int i=list.size()-1; i>=0; --i) {
  if(condition) {
     list.remove(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: No, what that means is that you can't safely modify the collection while traversing it **with an iterator**. I'm not using an iterator, I'm using a loop.

Comment: Oh woops you're not using an iterator, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Iterator itr = list.iterator(); 
while(itr.hasNext()) {
if(condition)
    itr.remove();
}
```

Hope so this shud work.. try else ll suggest another one

I have another one for you which checks for condition too....

```
int count=0;
Iterator itr = list.iterator(); 
while(itr.next()) {
count++;
if(condition=count)
    itr.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guava provides some functional flavour to Java.
In your case it would be:

```
 FluentIterable.from(your_iterable).filter(new Predicate<Type_contained_in_your_iterable>()                    {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(@Nullable Type_contained_in_your_iterable input) {
                return {condition};
            }
        });
```

Note that your predicate will only return the elements from your iterable satisfying your condition.
Much clearer like this. Isn't it.