# How to remove bean data from list

Tags: collections, jsf-2, arraylist, javabeans

I have `DrawingBean` as

```
public class DrawingBean {
    String drawingTitle;

    public String getDrawingTitle() {
        return drawingTitle;
    }

    public void setDrawingTitle(String drawingTitle) {
        this.drawingTitle = drawingTitle;
    }
}
```

In JSF I have page `drawingPatentss.xhtml` which contains below within `h:form` tag.

```
<h:inputText value="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.drawingTitle}" size="80" id="drawingTitle" />
<h:commandButton value="Upload More Drawing" action="# {PersonalInformationDataBean.checkMyDrawingPageData()}" />

<h:dataTable id="patentDrawingList" var="patentDrawingList" value="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.drawingList}"  border="1" width="30%">
<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="Drawing Title" />
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{patentDrawingList.drawingTitle}"/> 
<h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.removeDataFromDrawingList()}">
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.drawingTitle}" value="#{patentDrawingList.drawingTitle}" />
</h:commandButton>
</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

In `PersonalInformationDataBean.java` I have

```
private List<DrawingBean> drawingList = new ArrayList<DrawingBean>();
private String drawingTitle;
DrawingBean drawingBean;
// getter and setter for all of above.

public String checkMyDrawingPageData() {
drawingBean = new DrawingBean();
drawingBean.setDrawingTitle(drawingTitle);
drawingList.add(drawingBean);
return "drawingPatentss?faces-redirect=true";
}

public String removeDataFromDrawingList() {
    drawingBean = new DrawingBean();
    drawingBean.setDrawingTitle(drawingTitle);
    boolean removedStatus = false;
    removedStatus = drawingList.remove(drawingBean);
    System.out.println("removed status === " + removedStatus);
    return "drawingPatentss?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

However the bean is not getting removed from the list...

However if I add below lines in `removeDataFromDrawingList()`, the list gets updated.

```
    drawingBean = new DrawingBean();
    drawingBean.setDrawingTitle("Temp Title");
    drawingList.add(drawingBean);
```

Any reason why the request bean is not getting removed from the list that I have.

Any help would really appreciated.

Comment: my answer did the trick, however I am curious, why `remove(drawingBean)` is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution. I had to use `Iterator` class. Below code did the trick...

```
drawingBean = new DrawingBean();
drawingBean.setDrawingTitle(drawingTitle);
boolean removedStatus = false;

for (Iterator itr=drawingList.iterator();itr.hasNext();) {
    drawingBean = (DrawingBean) itr.next();
    if (drawingBean.getDrawingTitle().equals(drawingTitle)) {
        itr.remove();
        removedStatus = true;
    }
}
```

### [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1310591/1066828)